# level order traversal in a binary tree using queue

Tags: c++, data-structures

the following code crashes at runtime but **works perfectly fine if struct node* a[10] is declared globally**.Where does the problem lie.Any insight would be appreciated.
*Thank you!*

```
 #include<bits/stdc++.h>
    using namespace std;
    int rear=-1;
    int front=-1;

    struct node{
        int data;
        struct node *left;
        struct node *right;
    };

    struct node *newnode(int d){
        struct node* node1=new node;
        node1->data=d;
        node1->left=NULL;
        node1->right=NULL;
        return(node1);
    }

    void enqueue(struct node* a[],struct node* tempnode){
        rear++;
        a[rear]=tempnode;
    }

    struct node* dequeue(struct node* a[]){
       front++;
      return a[front];
    }

    void bfs(struct node* root,struct node* a[]){
        struct node *tempnode=root;
        while(tempnode){
            cout<<tempnode->data;
            if(tempnode->left)
                enqueue(a,tempnode->left);
            if(tempnode->right)
                enqueue(a,tempnode->right);
            tempnode=dequeue(a);
        }
    }

    main() {
        struct node* a[10];

        struct node* root=newnode(1);
        root->left=newnode(2);
        root->right=newnode(3);
        root->left->left=newnode(-1);
        root->left->right=newnode(0);
        bfs(root,a);
    }
```

http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/level-order-tree-traversal/

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but I suggest you read [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Comment: `struct node* c=new node; c=a[front];` produces memleak.

Comment: `main` seems to be missing the return type (`int`).

Comment: @Jarod42 i can't use delete(c) here.Further i modified the function                  
    f=-1;                                                                                                 
    struct node* dequeue(struct node* a[]){
    front++;
    return a[front];
}      Yet it crashes again..

Comment: Count the number of enqueues and the number of dequeues. If you have more dequeues than enqueues... that would be bad and give you a great place to start debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize the array "a" -

```
int main() {
    struct node* a[10] = {NULL};
```

The problem is not occurring when struct node* a[10] is declared globally because global variables are initialized automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You forget to initialize `a`:

```
struct node* a[10]{};
```

so your `dequeue` will indeed return `nullptr` once your queue is empty.

Comment: Future concern: `dequeue` and `enqueue` both easily overflow.